# React Hooks - Updating state using props without event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React and this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. User selects an item from the sidebar.
2. The elementID is lifted up to the parent(app.js).
3. app.js sends it to its child, Graphs.
4. Graphs will create a Graph component and append to its `graph` array.

Is there a better way than this? P.S I'll have more than 1x `useEffect` in this component.

```
App.js
 - Sidebar
 - Title-bar
 - Graphs

function Graphs(props) {
  const [graphs, addGraphs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.graphID) {
      addGraphs(graphs.concat(props.graphID));
    }
  }, [props.graphID]);

  return (
    <div>{graphs}</div>
  );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Should use a functional update, i.e. `addGraphs(graphs => graphs.concat(props.graphID))` but other than that, no, not really. This treads a fine-line of storing passed props in local state, though, which is a React anti-pattern generally. The [unrelated] question is then, why are you storing passed props into children state?

Comment: In my app so far the structure is: app.js > Title bar, Sidebar, Graphs.
When I select an item from the sidebar it lifts the element-ID to app.js which then sends it to Graphs. 

Graphs will hold a list of Components based on the user's selection(s) on the sidebar (for now it is just a list of IDs).

Comment: Right, that seems to me to be state belonging to the component rendering the list to select from... the entire list of selected graph ids should be passed to children. You want your source of truth to be as centralized as possible.

Comment: I guess the sidebar would have to be the parent of the main area, or I use contexts. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a good approach, but you should use an functional state update. The "setter" functions of `React.useState` hook has a callback with previous state, so you shall update it like this:

```
import React from "react";

function MyComponent({id}) {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      setList(previousState => {
         return [
             ...previousState,
             id
         ];
      });
    }
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
        {
            list.map((_id, index) => {
                <p key={index}>
                    {_id.toString()}
                </p>
            )
         }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the benefit of using a previous state vs modifying the current state? I.e.: in this case or for example incrementing a counter. Which way would you go for?

Comment: The benefit is ensuring you are correctly updating from the previous state, ***not*** the state from the previous render cycle. It's a subtle but extremely important distinction. If you ever enqueue more than a single update in a single render cycle, not using a functional update will overwrite the previous update. A good rule of thumb would be "anytime a state update ***depends*** on ***any*** previous state, use a functional update". Taking an array from previous state and appending an element is a dependency.

Comment: I would love to see a simplified example of this where all that happens is an update to a single variable in the code without involving a div.  I just want to increment the state variable by 1 to count the page views.  Why do you use useEffect?

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with sending props as you have done Jonathan.

If you are looking for other state management options you can look into the native React [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hooks to create your own system. Otherwise there are frameworks like [Redux Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/), and more recently [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) is worth checking out.

If you just simply want to select an ID and send it to another component, using `props` or `useContext` is probably your best bet.